How to add Schema.org BreadcrumbList when using template_preprocess_breadcrumb()
We had some specific breadcrumb requirement and decided to rewrite it completely using template_preprocess_breadcrumb() which is not very dedicated for this but was very easy to work with.
However we now need to implement Schema.org BreadcrumbList.
Is there a function that can be used to output it using our custom breadrumb ?
Here is a simplificated code that we use for this.
function propal_preprocess_breadcrumb(&$variables) {
  if ($pro) {
    $variables['breadcrumb'][0]['text'] = t('Home pro');
    $variables['breadcrumb'][0]['url'] = $home_pro_url;

    $variables['breadcrumb'][1]['text'] = $subsection_pro;
    $variables['breadcrumb'][1]['url'] = $subsection_pro_url;
  }
  else {
    $variables['breadcrumb'][0]['text'] = t('Home public');
    $variables['breadcrumb'][0]['url'] = $home_url;
  }

  // Adding the title of the page in the breadcrumb
  $variables['breadcrumb'][] = [
    'text' => $node->getTitle(),
  ];
}


You can attach the JSON-LD directly to the HTML <head> adding the following code snippet inside your preprocess hook right below your code:
// Prepare structured data.
$value = [
  '@context' => 'https://schema.org',
  '@type' => 'BreadcrumbList',
  'itemListElement' => [],
];
$position = 1;
foreach ($variables['breadcrumb'] as $key => $breadcrumb) {
  $value['itemListElement'][$key] = [
    '@type' => 'ListItem',
    'position' => $position,
    'name' => $breadcrumb['text'],
  ];
  if (!empty($breadcrumb['url'])) {
    $value['itemListElement'][$key]['item'] = $breadcrumb['url'];
  }
  $position++;
}

// Attach structured data.
$structured_data = [
  '#tag' => 'script',
  '#attributes' => ['type' => 'application/ld+json'],
  '#value' => json_encode($value, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE),
];
$variables['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
  $structured_data,
  'schema_org_breadcrumb_list',
];

